# How should a paint event of User Control's Panel should be raised kept in a form?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a user control that has a panel where I want to do some paint operations at run time. I want to know how I should deal with the paint event of user control's panel when I place it to the form. Because the paint event does not work correctly, and it ruins the control when I keep it to the form.

This is my paint event for the panel in usercontrol's

```
private void itemPnl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    drawString(e);
    this.Invalidate();
}

private void drawString(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
    cBasketItemHelper objHelper = new cBasketItemHelper() { CanvasWidth = this.itemPnl.Width, CanvasHeight = this.itemPnl.Height, X = 3, Y = 3 };
    objHelper.myBrush = myBrush;
    objHelper.currOrder = Program.currOrder;
    objHelper.g = e.Graphics;
    objHelper.DrawBasketItems();
    objHelper.g.Dispose();
    e.Dispose();
}
```

But when I write this paint event and after completing keeps the control to the form, it destypes and say some error, that `drawBasketItems` has object reference not set to an instance of object.

This is the class holding all.

```
public class cBasketItemHelper : uiITEM
{
    object tag;
    public cOrder currOrder { get; set; }
    public List<btnObject> lstAcceptedCustomizatio { get; set; }
    public List<btnObject> lstDeniedCustomization { get; set; }
    public float qtyWidth { get; set; }
    public float itemWidth { get; set; }
    public float priceWidth { get; set; }

    private Label _lbl;
    public List<Label> lstLable { get; set; }

    public override RectangleF itemRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new RectangleF(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public cBasketItemHelper()
    {
        this.format = new StringFormat();
        this.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10);
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    }

    public List<Label> drawLabel()
    {
        lstLable = new List<Label>();
        foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)
        {
            _lbl = new Label();
            _lbl.Width = 200;// (int)CanvasWidth;
            _lbl.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            _lbl.Height = 20;
            _lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            _lbl.Tag = item;
            _lbl.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.label_Paint);
            lstLable.Add(_lbl);
        }
        return lstLable;
    }

    private void label_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        cOrderItem orderItem = (cOrderItem)lbl.Tag;
        g.DrawString(orderItem.ProductInfo.ProductDesc, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Red, new Point(1, 1));
    }

    public void DrawBasketItems()
    {
        this.qtyWidth = (this.CanvasWidth) * 25 / 100;
        this.priceWidth = (this.CanvasWidth) * 25 / 100;
        this.itemWidth = this.CanvasWidth * 50 / 100;
        foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)
        {
            this.lstAcceptedCustomizatio = item.lstAcceptedCustomization;
            this.lstDeniedCustomization = item.lstDeniedCustomization;
            string basketItemDescription = item.AppropriateProductName + "\n" + "+++ ";
            string toMeasure = "+++ ";//basketItemDescription;

            foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstAcceptedCustomizatio)
            {
                System.Drawing.SizeF newString = g.MeasureString(custItem.BtnName + ", ", this.Font); //get the size of the text property
                System.Drawing.SizeF drawnString = g.MeasureString(toMeasure, this.Font);

                if (newString.Width > this.itemWidth - drawnString.Width)
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + custItem.BtnName + ", "; //+ "\n";
                    toMeasure = string.Empty;
                    toMeasure = custItem.BtnName + ", ";// string.Empty; //get the size of the text property
                }
                else
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                    toMeasure = toMeasure + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                }
            }

            string[] removeString = { ", " };
            foreach (string removeItem in removeString)
            {
                if (basketItemDescription.EndsWith(removeItem))
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription.Substring(0, basketItemDescription.LastIndexOf(removeItem));
                    break;//only allow one match at most
                }
            }

            basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + "--- ";
            toMeasure = "--- ";
            foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstDeniedCustomization)
            {
                System.Drawing.SizeF newString = g.MeasureString(custItem.BtnName + ", ", this.Font); //get the size of the text property
                System.Drawing.SizeF drawnString = g.MeasureString(toMeasure, this.Font);

                if (newString.Width > this.itemWidth - drawnString.Width)
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + custItem.BtnName + ", "; //+ "\n";
                    toMeasure = string.Empty;
                    toMeasure = custItem.BtnName + ", ";// string.Empty; //get the size of the text property
                }
                else
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                    toMeasure = toMeasure + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                }
            }

            foreach (string removeItem in removeString)
            {
                if (basketItemDescription.EndsWith(removeItem))
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription.Substring(0, basketItemDescription.LastIndexOf(removeItem));
                    break;//only allow one match at most
                }
            }

            System.Drawing.SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(basketItemDescription, this.Font); //get the size of the text property
            float stringHeight = mySize.Height;
            this.Height = mySize.Height;

            /*Draw Item*/
            this.Width = qtyWidth;
            g.DrawString(item.Quantity.ToString(), Font, myBrush, this.itemRectangle, format);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(itemRectangle));
            this.X = X + Width;
            this.Width = itemWidth;

            /*Draw Item Descrption*/
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

            g.DrawString(basketItemDescription, Font, myBrush, this.itemRectangle, format);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(itemRectangle));
            this.X = X + Width;
            this.Width = priceWidth;
            /*Draw item Total*/
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            g.DrawString(item.OrderItemPrice.ToString(), Font, myBrush, this.itemRectangle, format);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(itemRectangle));

            this.X = 3;
            this.Y = this.Y + this.Height + 2;
            this.Width = 0;
            this.Height = 0;
        }
    }

    public float GetTheActualHeight()
    {
        float actualHeight = 0;
        foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)
        {
            this.lstAcceptedCustomizatio = item.lstAcceptedCustomization;
            this.lstDeniedCustomization = item.lstDeniedCustomization;
            string basketItemDescription = item.AppropriateProductName + "\n" + "+++ ";
            string toMeasure = "+++ ";//basketItemDescription;

            foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstAcceptedCustomizatio)
            {
                System.Drawing.SizeF newString = g.MeasureString(custItem.BtnName + ", ", this.Font); //get the size of the text property
                System.Drawing.SizeF drawnString = g.MeasureString(toMeasure, this.Font);

                if (newString.Width > this.itemWidth - drawnString.Width)
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + custItem.BtnName + ", "; //+ "\n";
                    toMeasure = string.Empty;
                    toMeasure = custItem.BtnName + ", ";// string.Empty; //get the size of the text property
                }
                else
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                    toMeasure = toMeasure + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                }
            }

            string[] removeString = { ", " };
            foreach (string removeItem in removeString)
            {
                if (basketItemDescription.EndsWith(removeItem))
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription.Substring(0, basketItemDescription.LastIndexOf(removeItem));
                    break;//only allow one match at most
                }
            }

            basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + "--- ";
            toMeasure = "--- ";
            foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstDeniedCustomization)
            {
                System.Drawing.SizeF newString = g.MeasureString(custItem.BtnName + ", ", this.Font); //get the size of the text property
                System.Drawing.SizeF drawnString = g.MeasureString(toMeasure, this.Font);

                if (newString.Width > this.itemWidth - drawnString.Width)
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + "\n" + custItem.BtnName + ", "; //+ "\n";
                    toMeasure = string.Empty;
                    toMeasure = custItem.BtnName + ", ";// string.Empty; //get the size of the text property
                }
                else
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                    toMeasure = toMeasure + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
                }
            }

            foreach (string removeItem in removeString)
            {
                if (basketItemDescription.EndsWith(removeItem))
                {
                    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription.Substring(0, basketItemDescription.LastIndexOf(removeItem));
                    break;//only allow one match at most
                }
            }

            System.Drawing.SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(basketItemDescription, this.Font); //get the size of the text property
            actualHeight = actualHeight + mySize.Height;
        }
        return actualHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you invalidating the form in `itemPnl_Paint`?  That's asking for a redraw of the whole form.  And since your error seems to be happening in `drawBasketItems()` could you show us the code it uses?

Comment: I have posted the class, holding the method and relevant operations.

Comment: Most obvious thing to check is that `Program.currOrder` has a valid value at the time that you call `drawBasketItems()`.  If it is `null` it will cause an exception at the `foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)` line.

Comment: but if i uncomment the drawBaketItems and compile it tells this object reference error.

Comment: This error i am getting at compile time..when i compile and keep my control to the form it ruins and says object reference not set to an instance of object and some stack track like..